# Arrows to Empty Space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, node-connections, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying model a network and is new to tikz. Please let me know how to can I draw node with some **outgoing edges to somewhere** as given in the image below.[image: Image that I want in my writing]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can draw from nowhere to somewhere `\draw[<-]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the coordinates, in absolute or relative terms, from/to where the arrows should go. Moreover, you can define coordinates in the same way as nodes, by using `\coordinate` instead of `\node`, and use their names in `\draw` commands. One solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=2]\scriptsize
  \node[circle,draw] (N) {N};
  \draw[<-] (N) -- node[swap,sloped]         {$\mathrm{in}_1$}  +(150:1);
  \draw[<-] (N) -- node[swap]                {$\mathrm{in}_2$}  +(180:1);
  \draw[<-] (N) -- node[sloped]              {$\mathrm{in}_3$}  +(210:1);
  \draw[->] (N) -- node[sloped]              {$\mathrm{out}_1$} +( 30:1);
  \draw[->] (N) -- node[sloped,pos=0.8]      {$\mathrm{out}_2$} +( 10:1);
  \draw[->] (N) -- node[sloped,pos=0.8,swap] {$\mathrm{out}_3$} +(-10:1);
  \draw[->] (N) -- node[sloped,swap]         {$\mathrm{out}_3$} +(-30:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also note that instead of drawing the line in the direction of the arrow (which is annoying for the incoming arrows) you can just put the arrow on the other end of the line: `\draw[<-] (N) -- node {$\mathrm{in}_2$} +(180:1) ;'

Comment: @Emma Ah, yes, that's nice, I will change it.